# Using css for background block & underline (100%)

Tags: css

I'm trying to do something like this using css:

[image: text with styling]

I need it to:

1. Only have background (with padding) around the text, and
2. Have a solid line occupying 100% page width thereafter

For example, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
 <div style="my-custom-style">T E X T</div>
```

Would appreciate some input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:after` pseudo element to minimise markup.

The point is to position the pseudo element absolutly and keep the div's position to default static position. This way, setting the pseudo element to `width:100%;` will make it span the whole width of the divs parent (you will although need to set that parent to an other position than the default static position. In the following demo it is the `body` element) :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vY6dC/)**

*CSS :*

```
body{
    position:relative;
}

div{
    background-color:#FF7F27;
    display:inline-block;
}
div:after{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:inherit;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

1. As stated in comments by @Paulie_D, you should be using a text node to display text like `<span>` `<p>` `<li>` `<h1>` `<h2>` ... Using this technique, `<span>` or a title tag should suit you depending on the content you need to display.
2. As Stated by @KheemaPandey using a manual space between the letters isn't the best considering HTML semantics , maintainability of your code and the "concept" of CSS styling.
   You should be using [`letters-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) to space your letters.

Considering both points, your code could look like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vY6dC/4/)**

*HTML :*

```
<span>TEXT</span>
```

*CSS :*

```
body{
    position:relative;
}
span{
    background-color:#FF7F27;
    display:inline-block;
    letter-spacing:0.5em;
}
span:after{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:inherit;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that, as the question is stated, this is a bare text node...which would not be recommended anyway. Good answer though.

Comment: I was also using `pseudo element` but you beat me by placing `position:relative;` in body tag. so deserve +1 .

Comment: @Paulie_D what is a "bare text node"?

Comment: @Paulie_D are you talking about space between text? I guess that could be achieve using `letter-spacing`..correct me If I am wrong?

Comment: Raw text inside a div that's not wrapped in a 'proper' text tag like `p` or `span` or `li` or `a`. As it's not in an element you cannot select it by itself...only by selecting the containing element.

Comment: but why need to use an un-necessary extra element. like in this example `span`?

Comment: If you're interested in maximum backwards compatibility, I'd use a span for the inline-block rather than a div. This also deals with your text-node wrapper.

Comment: @KheemaPandey It's not unnecessary...it just properly formatted HTML. You cannot affect that text **directly** with CSS...only by applying styles to the `div`. If you wrap the text in a proper text tag...you can grab it directly with CSS. CSS selects **elements** not text.

Comment: @Paulie_D particular in this example is okay. And you are totally right when building a page or website.

Comment: @web-tiki what do you think about giving a manual space between text? while that could be control just using CSS.

Comment: @KheemaPandey well to be honest I would use letter spacing (easier to implement and maitain) but this question isn't about that and I didn't really notice. Ill although give info about that too and edit my answer

Comment: Excellent answer, this is what I used to solve my scenario. And even better that you recommended the `after` pseudo element as I used `hover` & `active` rules on it to modify the color which now, in turn, also modifies the lines color! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/qaZ8N/)

```
<div style="my-custom-style"><span>T E X T</span></div>

div{
 border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
}
span{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 3px 5px;
 background: orange
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was typing.